# How can I use a protocol in combination with a navigation controller?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, segue, protocols

Hey guys I have a little question again. How can I use a protocol in combination with a nav controller. So first of all here are my two classes:

First View Controller:

```
class VC1: UIViewController{

var cons = "nothing"

@IBAction func PRINT(_ sender: Any) {
    print(cons)
}

@IBAction func PRESENT(_ sender: Any) {
    let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "VC") as! VC2
    VC.delegate = self
    present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}  }

extension VC1: data {
func give(text: String) {
    cons = text
} }
```

Second View Controller:

```
protocol data {
func give(text: String)}

class VC2: UIViewController {

var delegate: data!

@IBAction func SAVEDISMISS(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate.give(text: "Hallo")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
```

And here is also my storyboard:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Noj.png)

So now I will come to my problem. When I run the code there is an error message when I perform any segue on VC2 because by using the protocol, the navigation controller is excluded, but when i present the navigation controller instead of VC2 the protocol isn´t working anymore.

What could I change so that the navigation controller isn´t excluded and the protocol is working both.

Hopefully anyone can help me, and sorry for my bad english again. I hope you can understand everything.

Have a great day or night.

Comment: Show the code you are using to present NavigationController.

Comment: I create a segue between VC1 to the navigation controller and give the segue an identifier. And than I write performSegue(withidentifer: xxx, sender: xxx) instead of present.... in ibaction PRESENT. But when I do this the protocol isn’t working anymore.

Comment: You could simply subclass `UINavigationController`, implement the protocol and route the `give` call up to the navigation controller's delegate. Btw, please try to use the swift naming conventions regarding when to use upper case Identifiers, lower case etc. Your style is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `PRESENT` function with the following code when you are trying to present a `UINavigationController`.

```swift
@IBAction func PRESENT(_ sender: Any) {
    let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "VC") as! VC2
    VC.delegate = self
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
    present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```